# reallyvisible selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jquery `:visible` and `:hidden` selectors are a little misleading, they select elements that consume space in the document, therefore something with `visibility:hidden` is classed as `:visible` even though it's not o_O

I need to be able to select only elements that are `:reallyvisible`, that I can see with my eyes eg, not `opacity:0` or `visibility:hidden`

Obviously for an element to be visually visible all it's ancestors must also be visible so I assume a recursive look up the tree would be necessary.

Is this just too expensive?
Can anyone suggest a reliable efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you produce a simple [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) where `:visible` fails (that way we don't all have to create our own version in order to help you)? And does it have to be a selector `:reallyvisible` or would a plugin method be acceptable `.reallyvisible()`?

Comment: Wouldn't a good test for `:reallyvisible` be to create a childnode and see if it is visible?

Comment: There are a few blog posts on this topic, e.g.: http://darshanmarathe.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/is-really-visible-jquery-selector.html - you can probably adapt that code to do exactly what you want it to.

Comment: I think first two commenters miss understood but, here's example http://jsfiddle.net/robaldred/6qvFB/

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks, seems like that's the article I was searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$.expr[':'].reallyVisible = function(node, idx){

   while(true){

      // should be faster than $(node).css()
      var css = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(node, null);

      if(css.opacity == 0 || css.visibility == 'hidden')
        return false;

     node = node.parentNode;

     if(!node || node === document)
         break;
   }        

   return true;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jxEFk/

Comment: looks decent, just checking some edge cases

Comment: just amended it to check the display property aswell, but otherwise. great work thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
function isVisible(el){
    if (el.css('opacity') != '0' && el.css('visibility') != 'hidden') {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

$('myelement').filter(function () {
    visible = true

    if (isVisible($(this)) == false)
        visible = false

    $(this).parents().each(function(){
        if (isVisible($(this)) == false)
            visible = false
    })

    return visible == true
}).html("I'm really visible !")
```

Comment: This is missing parents check and display:none

Comment: I suspect the OP already knows how to do a test like this one, but he said _"Obviously for an element to be visually visible all it's ancestors must also be visible so I assume a recursive look up the tree would be necessary."_ Perhaps you'd like to comment on how that might be done efficiently?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @onetrickpony's will be much more efficient